# jQuery Attach handler for validation

Tags: jquery, handler

I need to do field validation(required field) using jQuery. For this we are using some existing jQuery code(3rd Party).
Current scenario:
     
     input control for name
      input control for phone(required, regex)
      input control for email(required, regex)
     
Here I am passing div id and 3rd party code will loop through all the child elements and do the validation and returns true if it pas else false.(no validation message)

but for regex they have mentioned

```
   function validateUsingRegularExpression() {
    // Construct a jQuery object out of the element that changed.
    var $element = jquery(this);
    var validateSuccess = false;
    var value = $element.val();

    //Do some regex validation if it returns true set 

    validateSucess = true;

    triggerResult(validateSuccess, $element);
  }

   function triggerResult(validateSuccess, $element) {
    if (validateSuccess) {
        $events.trigger('ValidatorSuccess', [$element]);
    }
    else {`enter code here`
        // If one validation fails then it fails for the group.
        me.IsValid = false;

        var message = $element.attr('Regex failed');
        $events.trigger('ValidatorFailure', [$element, message]);
    }
   }





 // Attach custom event handling for RequiredFieldValidator exception if    the default behavior
// is not adequate.
    this.OnValidatorSuccess = function (handler) { $events.on ('ValidatorSuccess', handler); }
    this.OffValidatorSuccess = function (handler) { $events.off('ValidatorSuccess', handler); }

      this.OnValidatorFailure = function (handler) { $events.on('ValidatorFailure', handler); }
      this.OffValidatorFailure = function (handler) { $events.off('ValidatorFailure', handler); }
```

Can some one please help me how to add handler